# Problems passing Facebook friend name into text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on selecting a facebook friend. I'd want to display the facebook friend's name in the textfield that launches the facebook friend picker.

Thanks!

Also, is there a difference between grabbing the users string name and selecting a friend to send an object to? Because that's what the users will be doing. So, I'll need to display the string value of the user's name, but I'll also have to associate an object with that user.

```
-(IBAction)cancelList;
-(IBAction)submitList;
-(IBAction)datePicker;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *listFieldText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dateFieldText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *wallPostText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *friendsName;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIDatePicker *pick;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *profilePic;

@property (retain, nonatomic) PF_FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController;
```

Implementation:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    sender.delegate = self;
    if([sender isEqual:dateFieldText])
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Save Date"
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(datePicker)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
        pick = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
        [pick setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,120)];
        //[pick addTarget:self action:@selector(done) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        dateFieldText.delegate = self;
        dateFieldText.inputView = pick;
    }
    else if ([sender isEqual:friendsName])
    {
        NSLog(@"Pick a friend!");

        if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
            // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
            self.friendPickerController = [[PF_FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
            self.friendPickerController.title = @"Select Friends";
            self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
            self.friendPickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
        }
        [self.friendPickerController loadData];
        [self.friendPickerController clearSelection];
        [self presentModalViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES];

    }
    else{
        UIBarButtonItem *submitButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                         initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                         target:self
                                         action:@selector(submitList)]; //change this


          self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = submitButton;

        }
    }

-(void)updateFriendTextField:(NSString*)subtitle
{
    friendsName.text = subtitle;
}

/*
-(void)updateSelections
{
    NSString* friendsSubtitle = @"Selected friends";
    id<PF_FBGraphUser> friend = [self.selectedFriends objectAtIndex:0];
    friendsSubtitle = friend.name;
    [self updateFriendTextField:friendsSubtitle];

    //[self handlePickerDone];
}
*/

-(void)friendPickerViewControllerDataDidChange:(PF_FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker {
    NSLog(@"Current friend selections: %@", friendPicker.selection); 

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    friendPickerController.delegate = nil;
}

- (void)facebookViewControllerCancelWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Friend selection cancelled.");
    //[self handlePickerDone];
}

- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Done was pressed.");
    //[self updateSelections];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify your question? Its not clear about what's your requirement.

Comment: Basically I can launch facebook friend picker, and select friends, but I don't know how to pass data [like the users name, etc] into another view. The friend picker presents modally from a tableview.

Comment: Don't use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions not about the IDE.

Comment: Are you using Parse? Where's the PF_FBFriendPickerViewController class from?

Comment: @k20 I am. They've actually updated it recently so I don't need PF_ but I just haven't updated yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it from friendPicker.selection in one of your delegate methods (`friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange` or `friendPickerViewControllerDataDidChange`).

The items in the array are `PF_FBGraphUser` objects, so you can save them and use whatever you need from  `PF_FBGraphUser`:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *id;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *first_name;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *middle_name;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *last_name;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *link;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *username;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *birthday;
@property (retain, nonatomic) id<PF_FBGraphPlace> location;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this answer.

Personally, I like using a global header since it's the most efficient from my viewpoint.

I would create a header file and name it "global.h"

In that header file, I would create the following:

`NSString* friendsName;

NSString* wallPostText;

NSString* dateFieldText;

NSString* listFieldText;`

Next I would initialize these objects in the app delegate when the app first launches just by simply calling `friendsName = @"friend";`

Later when you actually receive the friend name from the selection, save that name into the that global variable, friendsName!

Remember to #import "global.h" into all classes that need to access those variables!

A second method in doing this is creating a local variable in the class in which you wish to access these variables.

`@property(nonatomic) NSString *friendsName;`

When you are pushing your new UIViewController, you can pass it through right after initialization like so:

`ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];

viewControllerB.friendsName = "Mark";

[self pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand. The selection is coming out as an Array. Also, keep in mind I present a model view controller for adding an item to a list, and this model view controller has a few different text boxes. One of them has the friendsName text box that launches the friend picker. I make a selection, hit done, and it dismisses both the friend picker and the original model view controller, and goes to the beginning table view. I need friend picker to populate the first modal view controller's text box with the friend's name.